# 3 tables to join

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am stuck in my liaison of my 3 tables. 
I have a table which is candidates with 3 fields (id_candidate, name_candidate, firstname_candidate)

An other table nammed lessons with 5 fields (id_lesson, price_lesson, date_lesson, fk_candidate, fk_monitor)

I have a table which is monitors with 3 fields (id_monitor, name_monitor, firstname_monitor)

I can join 2 tables (candidates and lessons) 
Here is the request

```
SELECT *
FROM lessons INNER JOIN
     candidates
     ON lessons.fk_candidate=candidates.id_candidate
ORDER BY id_candidate ASC
```

But my problem is that. I don't understand how to join 3 tables? 
In fact, the name of monitor must appear on the table lessons.

I have tried that

```
SELECT *
FROM candidates id_candidate INNER JOIN
     lessons id_lesson
     ON lessons.fk_candidate = candidates.id_candidate INNER JOIN 
     monitors id_monitor 
     ON lessons.fk_monitor = monitors.id_monitor;
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Comment: This is wrong: `JOIN lessons id_lesson ON`. This makes `id_lesson` an alias name for the table `lessons`. Remove it: `JOIN lessons ON`. Same for `JOIN monitors id_monitor ON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, something like this:

```
SELECT c.*, l.*, m.name_monitor  -- list out the columns you want explicitly
FROM candidates c INNER JOIN
     lessons l
     ON l.fk_candidate = c.id_candidate INNER JOIN 
     monitors m 
     ON l.fk_monitor = m.id_monitor;
```

Notes:

- Using table aliases is a good idea.  I recommend abbreviations for the table name.
- After you have defined the table alias, *use them*.  Your `on` clauses still referred to the table name.
- Explicitly list the columns that you want.

Comment: thank you a lot... I was stuck since 1 hour thank very much